# Не работает django channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Не запускается django channels, даже не появляется такая строка `Starting ASGI/Channels development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'djchannels.routing.application'
```

Всё делаю по [документации](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html)
Никаких ошибок не выскакивает, но channels не запускается. Если нужна доп. информацию предоставлю.

Comment: Покажите настройки. Подключили в `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Да подключил.
`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'chat',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]`

Comment: Весь день на эту проблему убил, не знаю почему не работает

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась установкой [этого](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)

Comment: Зачем кидать ссылку на загрузку файла, если можно было скинуть на страницу описания ?